# 'kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates' and 'kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot' is deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

I have added the "ASIHTTPRequest" library to my app. Now, I'm trying to remove all warnings in my project. I have fixed all other warnings except  those for "ASIHTTPRequest". I'm getting the warnings below.

> 'kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates' is deprecated:
>
> 'kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot' is deprecated:

How to resolve this?

Code:

```
NSDictionary *sslProperties = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates,
                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot,
                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],  kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain,
                      kCFNull,kCFStreamSSLPeerName,
                      nil];
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Related: [Issue #395](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/issues/395) for `ASIHTTPRequest` on GitHub.

Answer (score 29):

As per the comments in CFSocketStream.h in the CFNetwork framework:

> kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates:
>   kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredRoots:
>   kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot:
>
> The SSL handshake flags which affect untrusted certificate chain evaluation are deprecated. Instead, use the single property **`kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain`** to disable certificate chain checking if the user has decided that it is appropriate to do so

So the simple solution is to remove the deprecated keys and their values. Keep only **`kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain`** and **`kCFStreamSSLPeerName`** in the `sslProperties` dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line above your declaration:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
```