# How can I remove the deprecated API warnings from my SSL properties

Tags: ios, deprecation-warning

```
 NSDictionary *sslProperties = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],  kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain,
                                  kCFNull,kCFStreamSSLPeerName,
                                  nil];
```

These keys are deprecated

```
kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates
kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot
```

How can I fix it so I'm not using deprecated API/keys.

I saw this ['kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates' and 'kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot' is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864785/kcfstreamsslallowsexpiredcertificates-and-kcfstreamsslallowsanyroot-is-depre)

but I didn't understand the popular response

Comment: So remove `kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates
kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot` from your dictionary only keep the `SSL peerName` and the `CertifcateChain` in the dictionary you don't need the others anymore

Comment: Can you answer the question so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove `kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates` and `kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot` from your `NSDictionary` because it is not required anymore.